# Facebook connect Android - Generate no expire tokens

Tags: android, facebook

As part of an Android app i have a Facebook connect login. What ive noticed is when the user sets up a profile and i save the url to their profile image it expires after a few weeks.

Can i get a url with a no expire token?

```
String token = login_result.getAccessToken().getToken();
String picUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&method=GET&access_token="+ token;
```

Thats what im using now.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just link to `https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture`

Comment: Ill check it out thanks

Comment: Seems to work but its tiny. I assume thats all thats public maybe

Comment: Add `?type=large` like you did on your call

Comment: Perfect result.